# Не накатывается GinIndex в django?

Tags: python, django-orm

```
class RequestHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("accounts.User", verbose_name=_("Owner"),
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    request = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Request"))
    response = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Response"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "request_history"
        ordering = ["created_at"]
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["request"]),
                   GinIndex(fields=["response"])]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"RequestHistory {self.user.first_name}"
```

при применении миграции ошибка

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: data type text has no default operator class for access method "gin"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```